# Pull Configurable SKU instead of Simple Product SKU in Transactional Emails and Invoices

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, transactional, sku

Is it possible to have Magento pull the SKU of a configurable product instead of the individual simple product SKU in transactional emails and on invoices?